# How to disable D/libc from logging network information into logcat?

Tags: android, logcat, android-logcat

I am getting a lot of debugging log in my Android logcat like this:

```
10-16 17:21:38.422  22842-23270/package D/libc﹕ [NET] getaddrinfo+,hn 23(0x696d616765732e),sn(),family 0,flags 4
10-16 17:21:38.422  22842-23270/package D/libc﹕ [NET] getaddrinfo-,err=8
10-16 17:21:38.422  22842-23270/package D/libc﹕ [NET] getaddrinfo+,hn 23(0x696d616765732e),sn(),family 0,flags 1024
10-16 17:21:38.422  22842-23270/package D/libc﹕ [NET] getaddrinfo-, 1
10-16 17:21:38.422  22842-23270/package D/libc﹕ [NET] getaddrinfo_proxy+
10-16 17:21:38.432  22842-23270/package D/libc﹕ [NET] getaddrinfo_proxy-, success
```

I am not sure where they come from because I did not have such tag in my codes, but they are clearly related to network activities.

Answer (score 5):

You can add `^(?!(libc))` in a logcat filter

1) Create logcat filter 
[image: Add filter]

2) Apply regex 
[image: apply regex]

You can also remove differents tags by adding tag's name seperate by `|` in the regex.

Example : `^(?!(libc|tagname2|tagname3|...))`

Comment: Yes. This is a valid solution. However, I am more interested in removing the "logging action" from the root, rather than filtering the result. Thanks anyway!